# Error message with Lattice plot

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to use xyplot in lattice to plot distributions, but keep getting the following:

> ```
> Error in factor.levels[level] : 
>   object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
> ```

data

```
 data<-structure(list(SAMS = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("ET_Close", "ET_Open"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor"), 
    Gear = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "SURVEY", class = "factor"), 
    Totnum = c(159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 
    159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 
    159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 
    159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 
    159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 
    159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 
    159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 
    159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 159608.250877193, 
    159608.250877193, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 
    73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 
    73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 
    73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 
    73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 
    73457.27, 73457.27, 73457.27, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 
    61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 
    61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 
    61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 
    61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 
    61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 
    61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 
    61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 61685.2133333333, 
    61685.2133333333, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 
    177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 
    177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 
    177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 
    177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 
    177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 
    177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 
    177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 
    177260.582105263, 177260.582105263, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 
    52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 
    52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 
    52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 
    52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 52880.77, 
    52880.77, 52880.77, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 
    43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 
    43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 
    43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 
    43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205, 43688.205), Interval = c(2.5, 
    17.5, 22.5, 27.5, 32.5, 37.5, 42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 
    67.5, 72.5, 77.5, 82.5, 87.5, 92.5, 97.5, 102.5, 107.5, 112.5, 
    117.5, 122.5, 127.5, 132.5, 137.5, 142.5, 147.5, 152.5, 157.5, 
    162.5, 167.5, 2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5, 27.5, 32.5, 37.5, 
    42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5, 77.5, 82.5, 87.5, 
    92.5, 97.5, 102.5, 107.5, 112.5, 117.5, 122.5, 127.5, 132.5, 
    137.5, 142.5, 147.5, 152.5, 2.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5, 27.5, 
    32.5, 37.5, 42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5, 77.5, 
    82.5, 87.5, 92.5, 97.5, 102.5, 107.5, 112.5, 117.5, 122.5, 
    127.5, 132.5, 137.5, 142.5, 147.5, 152.5, 157.5, 7.5, 12.5, 
    17.5, 22.5, 27.5, 32.5, 37.5, 42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 
    67.5, 72.5, 77.5, 82.5, 87.5, 92.5, 97.5, 102.5, 107.5, 112.5, 
    117.5, 122.5, 127.5, 132.5, 137.5, 142.5, 147.5, 152.5, 157.5, 
    162.5, 167.5, 2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5, 27.5, 32.5, 37.5, 
    42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5, 77.5, 82.5, 87.5, 
    92.5, 97.5, 102.5, 107.5, 112.5, 117.5, 122.5, 127.5, 132.5, 
    137.5, 142.5, 2.5, 17.5, 22.5, 27.5, 32.5, 37.5, 42.5, 47.5, 
    52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5, 77.5, 82.5, 87.5, 92.5, 97.5, 
    102.5, 107.5, 112.5, 117.5, 122.5, 127.5, 132.5, 137.5, 142.5
    ), Total_len = c(0, 115.15, 748.3, 2477.16666666667, 5497.5, 
    12447.2333333333, 21067.1464912281, 28781.0105263158, 27290.4377192982, 
    17257.9666666667, 6910.00526315789, 2230.81403508772, 616.9, 
    851.280701754386, 2293.05701754386, 5486.77543859649, 8042.88157894737, 
    5427.93245614035, 1601.13771929825, 638.890350877193, 938.466666666667, 
    1856.29035087719, 2176.17807017544, 2138.19210526316, 1501.78771929825, 
    755.716666666667, 224.966666666667, 138.05, 34.3, 24.05, 
    37.6666666666667, 1, 0, 1, 7, 6, 3.33, 30, 52.25, 222.26, 
    562.89, 1030.94333333333, 1609.71833333333, 2685.73, 4993.40666666667, 
    9019.255, 11521.7533333333, 13397.45, 11497.38, 7903.61166666667, 
    3746.61333333333, 1367.71833333333, 1049.31, 1017.63166666667, 
    573.103333333333, 262.931666666667, 193.696666666667, 280.306666666667, 
    214.07, 154.6, 24.18, 20.13, 9, 0, 5.8, 69.7, 134.4, 78.5, 
    37.4333333333333, 130.741666666667, 390.9, 760.083333333333, 
    1445.04166666667, 2070.96333333333, 3259.32333333333, 4837.90666666667, 
    6398.71, 8081.145, 8039.49, 8027.985, 6061.39833333333, 4682.04666666667, 
    2836.75833333333, 1763.26666666667, 1000.435, 512.731666666667, 
    461.376666666667, 247.441666666667, 184.66, 106.1, 40.8, 
    17.075, 2, 1, 4.75, 11, 50.35, 202.25, 847.673684210526, 
    3170.29070175439, 10974.9605263158, 23416.9806140351, 33056.3594736842, 
    32436.6875438597, 21245.1093859649, 9004.90289473684, 2252.90438596491, 
    907.376666666667, 1148.74035087719, 2320.57666666667, 3763.12166666667, 
    3288.86, 1750.43070175439, 2355.79035087719, 3885.26307017544, 
    5668.15236842105, 6339.69368421053, 4644.55, 2720.67736842105, 
    1198.01, 424.715, 117.88, 32.79, 8.13, 3.405, 7.2, 1, 0, 
    3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 35.5, 103.5, 229.57, 223.76, 206.63, 569.61, 
    1170.62, 3255.98, 7191.72, 10920.51, 10570.75, 7905.61, 3981.34, 
    1412.47, 1213.41, 1327.9, 934.87, 592.55, 522.73, 304.84, 
    137.21, 31.98, 23.71, 0, 18.73, 59.7, 30.15, 79.8, 553.725, 
    2103.605, 2761.8, 1332.71, 376.43, 77.6, 119.59, 299.49, 
    628.56, 1303.32, 2776.13, 5807.555, 8039.27, 8532.37, 5270.03, 
    2164.655, 701.405, 357.94, 174.385, 84.5, 31.18, 3.575), 
    fraction = c(0, 0.000721453930903607, 0.004688354116328, 
    0.0155202920466353, 0.0344437080776603, 0.0779861521251215, 
    0.131992841068334, 0.180322823965164, 0.170983878147354, 
    0.1081270333571, 0.0432935341699512, 0.0139768089859225, 
    0.00386508840620439, 0.00533356325300116, 0.0143667824497883, 
    0.0343765150513313, 0.0503913897605192, 0.0340078437443485, 
    0.0100316726140317, 0.00400286543688003, 0.00587981298904622, 
    0.0116302906690299, 0.0136344960753304, 0.0133965010800622, 
    0.00940921105923129, 0.00473482205658739, 0.00140949271375552, 
    0.000864930222850569, 0.000214901170907457, 0.000150681433245608, 
    0.000235994483115089, 0.00000626534025969264, 0, 0.0000136133564451823, 
    0.0000952934951162764, 0.0000816801386710941, 0.0000453324769624572, 
    0.00040840069335547, 0.000711297874260778, 0.00302570460350623, 
    0.00766282220942869, 0.0140345990714511, 0.0219136694480115, 
    0.0365617998055196, 0.0679770248290832, 0.122782333184993, 
    0.156849735000135, 0.182384262306508, 0.156517932125711, 
    0.107594682822635, 0.0510039827689395, 0.0186192371882774, 
    0.0142846310514943, 0.0138533826082383, 0.00780185995658882, 
    0.0035793824990592, 0.002636861765577, 0.00381591456729425, 
    0.00291421121422019, 0.00210462490642519, 0.000329170958844509, 
    0.000274036865241521, 0.000122520208006641, 0, 0.0000940257751668633, 
    0.00112993043605696, 0.00217880416938387, 0.00127259023286186, 
    0.000606844514439009, 0.00211949768188638, 0.00633701301943567, 
    0.0123219697600138, 0.0234260625615085, 0.0335730918549686, 
    0.0528380005062261, 0.0784289525031499, 0.103731666865166, 
    0.131006193596693, 0.130330910206249, 0.130144398733267, 
    0.0982633925666897, 0.0759022529656486, 0.045987655388401, 
    0.0285849164067629, 0.0162183924791484, 0.00831206765705709, 
    0.0074795342633167, 0.00401136112360585, 0.00299358614522638, 
    0.00172002323193176, 0.000661422694277245, 0.000276808639823136, 
    0.0000324226810920218, 0.0000162113405460109, 0.0000267967076694992, 
    0.0000620555335504192, 0.000284045101296692, 0.00114097560550657, 
    0.00478207661366671, 0.0178849164552092, 0.0619142755595742, 
    0.132104838740343, 0.186484547670357, 0.182988722922041, 
    0.119852418025734, 0.050800368518419, 0.0127095621553757, 
    0.00511888574374554, 0.00648051776223455, 0.0130913293813321, 
    0.0212293202581948, 0.0185538147338756, 0.00987490101276393, 
    0.0132899842869649, 0.0219183702548615, 0.0319763835879492, 
    0.0357648249199916, 0.0262018207592363, 0.0153484623378108, 
    0.00675846815897616, 0.00239599235744239, 0.000665009663174856, 
    0.000184981904101659, 0.0000458646807059008, 0.0000192090083399252, 
    0.0000406181674148199, 0.0000056414121409472, 0, 0.0000567313978219304, 
    0.0000567313978219304, 0.0000189104659406435, 0.0000756418637625738, 
    0.0000567313978219304, 0.000671321540892843, 0.0019572332248566, 
    0.00434127566599352, 0.00423140585887838, 0.00390746957731516, 
    0.0107715905044499, 0.022136969639436, 0.0615720988934163, 
    0.135998776114644, 0.206511932409456, 0.199897807842057, 
    0.14949876864501, 0.0752889944681214, 0.0267104658271807, 
    0.0229461484770362, 0.0251112077225804, 0.0176788272939293, 
    0.0112053965931283, 0.00988506786115255, 0.00576466643734575, 
    0.00259470503171569, 0.000604756700781778, 0.000448367147452656, 
    0, 0.000428719834106254, 0.00136650155345133, 0.000690117618702805, 
    0.00182657996591986, 0.0126744735793105, 0.0481504103910884, 
    0.0632161472415724, 0.0305050299045246, 0.00861628441818564, 
    0.00177622312475415, 0.00273735210682151, 0.0068551683457812, 
    0.0143874073105086, 0.0298323082854972, 0.0635441533933472, 
    0.132931874861876, 0.184014655671937, 0.195301454935033, 
    0.120628210749332, 0.0495478127334369, 0.0160547909899251, 
    0.0081930580576611, 0.00399158079394656, 0.00193416049022843, 
    0.000713693776157661, 0.0000818298668942796)), .Names = c("SAMS", 
"Year", "Gear", "Totnum", "Interval", "Total_len", "fraction"
), row.names = c(51L, 58L, 44L, 55L, 38L, 43L, 60L, 40L, 54L, 
47L, 62L, 48L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 56L, 63L, 49L, 52L, 57L, 59L, 50L, 
34L, 33L, 41L, 53L, 61L, 46L, 39L, 36L, 42L, 45L, 98L, 110L, 
93L, 106L, 115L, 102L, 101L, 99L, 95L, 100L, 120L, 111L, 119L, 
121L, 107L, 94L, 92L, 97L, 103L, 113L, 114L, 112L, 116L, 109L, 
118L, 96L, 105L, 104L, 117L, 122L, 108L, 151L, 149L, 176L, 155L, 
177L, 179L, 150L, 153L, 175L, 165L, 162L, 161L, 159L, 172L, 152L, 
156L, 154L, 166L, 178L, 174L, 163L, 171L, 160L, 173L, 158L, 157L, 
168L, 167L, 164L, 170L, 169L, 239L, 218L, 240L, 227L, 237L, 231L, 
224L, 238L, 234L, 243L, 230L, 220L, 222L, 211L, 217L, 219L, 221L, 
226L, 214L, 223L, 235L, 242L, 228L, 216L, 213L, 215L, 236L, 241L, 
229L, 225L, 212L, 232L, 233L, 277L, 279L, 271L, 295L, 276L, 272L, 
275L, 281L, 289L, 298L, 288L, 285L, 284L, 282L, 291L, 270L, 274L, 
273L, 290L, 296L, 297L, 286L, 294L, 287L, 292L, 280L, 293L, 283L, 
278L, 344L, 345L, 325L, 333L, 341L, 339L, 337L, 336L, 348L, 332L, 
334L, 329L, 328L, 323L, 322L, 324L, 326L, 335L, 347L, 346L, 331L, 
343L, 342L, 340L, 330L, 338L, 327L), class = "data.frame")
```

lattice plot

```
xyplot(fraction~Interval|Year, data=data,type="l",
   groups=SAMS,
   ylab=list("Fraction of Total",cex=1.2),
   xlab=list("Length Interval (mm)",cex=1.2),
   scales=list(relation="same",
               y=list(alternating=1,cex=1.2),
               x=list(alternating=1,cex=1.2,
                      abbreviate=F)),
   strip = strip.custom(factor.levels=names,bg="white", strip.levels = T),
   drop.unused.levels=T,
   as.table=T,
   par.strip.text=list(cex=1.5))
```

I can use the xyplot function if I add `subset = Year== 2015`, etc., but I haven't had this type of problem before with lattice.

R session info
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Comment: You have `factor.levels=names` in there, but you haven't defined a `names` variable. And `names()` is a built in function which is probably not what you want. Seems like just some sort of typo here. Not sure what you were trying do there.

Comment: Thanks - sorry I should have looked at my code more closely.  That was left over from another graph where I set the factor levels names.  Point taken though I should not have used names.